# How can I prevent user Input to be shown on input filed in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, keydown, preventdefault

I want a user to input his name, but I want to limit the amount of characters to 15, in the desktop browsers it works.

```
document.querySelector('#input-name').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {

const maxLetters = 15

document.querySelector('#input-name').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    userName = e.target.value
    document.querySelector('#labelInputName').textContent = userName.length + "/" + maxLetters

})

userName = e.target.value

if (userName.length >= maxLetters && e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 8) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

else if (e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 8) {
    document.querySelector('#labelInputName').textContent = userName.length + 1 + "/" + maxLetters
}
```

})

So in the desktop browser it works after I am getting to 15/15 pressing any key from the keyboard except Delete and BackSpace won't do anything(won't even show the 16 character in the input field)...

But in the mobile browser I am getting to 15/15 and than keep going 16/15.... 
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far, the most cross-browser way to do this is with the [`maxlength` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-maxlength) of the `input` element; no JavaScript required:

```
<input id="input-name" maxlength="15">
```

Live Example:

```html
<input id="input-name" maxlength="15">
```

`maxlength` has been part of HTML basically forever (it's in the [HTML+ spec](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/HTMLPlus/htmlplus_1.html) from 1993), I expect browser support for it is universal.

If you need to set the max length from JavaScript, you'd use the `maxLength` property:

```
document.getElementById("input-name").maxLength = 15;
```

Live Example:

```js
document.getElementById("input-name").maxLength = 15;
```

```html
<input id="input-name">
```

Comment: it's works but when I add "addEventListener" for keydown and keyup it's stops the limiting for the mobile any idea why?

Comment: @EddieKnaz - Adding an event handler for those events won't, by itself, defeat the length restriction. But your code can assign a value that breaks the limit. So I guess your code is assigning to the `input`'s `value` and using a string longer than the limit. To avoid that, just make sure you respect the limit when assigning: `input.value = theString.substring(0, input.maxLength);`.

Answer (score 1):

How about a maxlength attribute which is supported for a long time? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp